# Nightwatch.js click not reflected in UI

Tags: selenium-webdriver, nightwatch.js

I am trying to click an element in Nightwatch:

```
client
    .waitForElementVisible('.tt-suggestions div:nth-child(4)', 2000)   
    .click('.tt-suggestions div:nth-child(4)', function(clickStatus) {
        console.log(clickStatus);
    });
```

I check the clickStatus, and it returns 'success' so the click is being fired on the element. However, it does not reflect in the UI. Any suggestions?

Comment: what would happen after the 'click' ? Some element would be visible/NotVisible ?

Comment: It is supposed to take the value of the clicked element (suggestion for typed text) and autocomplete the input field.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that sometimes you need to add a pause in order for the click to be performed in the browser. Therefore try this in your test:

```
client
.waitForElementVisible('.tt-suggestions div:nth-child(4)', 2000)
.pause(1000)   
.click('.tt-suggestions div:nth-child(4)', function(clickStatus) {
    console.log(clickStatus);
});
```